# Unrecognized keyword "as"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou utilizando o MYSQL junto com o PHPMyAdmin 4.7.4, e ele acusa que a keyword 'as' não é reconhecível, porém ao executar ele fica em loop infinito, e não mostra nenhum resultado.

```
   SELECT 
    c.`nome`, 
    case c.`id_estado`
        when c.`id_estado` = 1 then 12 
        when c.`id_estado` = 2 then 27
        when c.`id_estado` = 3 then 13 
        when c.`id_estado` = 4 then 16 
        when c.`id_estado` = 5 then 29
        when c.`id_estado` = 6 then 23
        when c.`id_estado` = 7 then 53 
        when c.`id_estado` = 8 then 32 
        when c.`id_estado` = 9 then 52 
        when c.`id_estado` = 10 then 21
        when c.`id_estado` = 11 then 31
        when c.`id_estado` = 12 then 50 
        when c.`id_estado` = 13 then 51
        when c.`id_estado` = 14 then 15 
        when c.`id_estado` = 15 then 25 
        when c.`id_estado` = 16 then 26 
        when c.`id_estado` = 17 then 22 
        when c.`id_estado` = 18 then 41 
        when c.`id_estado` = 19 then 33 
        when c.`id_estado` = 20 then 24 
        when c.`id_estado` = 21 then 11 
        when c.`id_estado` = 22 then 14 
        when c.`id_estado` = 23 then 43 
        when c.`id_estado` = 24 then 42 
        when c.`id_estado` = 25 then 28 
        when c.`id_estado` = 26 then 35 
        when c.`id_estado` = 27 then 17
    end as teste,
    c.`cod_municipio`, cll.`latitude`, cll.`longitude`
    FROM `cidade` c
    INNER JOIN  cidades_lat_long cll ON c.`cod_municipio` = cll.id_geocode
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando esse exemplo de código https://talibamartins.wordpress.com/2007/09/20/if-e-case-no-mysql/

A estrutura

```
CREATE TABLE cidades_lat_long (
    id_geocode int(11) NOT NULL,
    latitude double NOT NULL,
    longitude double NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_geocode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE cidade (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    id_estado int(11) NOT NULL,
    cod_municipio int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'CEP',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY fk_cidade_estado(id_estado)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10036 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você está usando o `case` baseado num campo, não precisa repetir o campo em cada `when`:

```
 SELECT 
    c.`nome`, 
    case c.`id_estado`
     WHEN 1 THEN 12
     WHEN 2 THEN 27
     WHEN 3 THEN 13
     WHEN 4 THEN 16
     WHEN 5 THEN 29
     WHEN 6 THEN 23
     WHEN 7 THEN 53
     WHEN 8 THEN 32
     WHEN 9 THEN 52
     WHEN 10 THEN 21
     WHEN 11 THEN 31
     WHEN 12 THEN 50
     WHEN 13 THEN 51
     WHEN 14 THEN 15
     WHEN 15 THEN 25
     WHEN 16 THEN 26
     WHEN 17 THEN 22
     WHEN 18 THEN 41
     WHEN 19 THEN 33
     WHEN 20 THEN 24
     WHEN 21 THEN 11
     WHEN 22 THEN 14
     WHEN 23 THEN 43
     WHEN 24 THEN 42
     WHEN 25 THEN 28
     WHEN 26 THEN 35
     WHEN 27 THEN 17
    end as teste,
    c.`cod_municipio`, cll.`latitude`, cll.`longitude`
    FROM `cidade` c
    INNER JOIN  cidades_lat_long cll ON c.`cod_municipio` = cll.id_geocode
```

Veja um fiddle funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8a28d/8

EDIT: copiado código completo do link que o @Sorack postou

Comment: Não me parece responder à questão.

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack, "descaradamente" copiado :)

Comment: @EricWu, o script funciona, acredito que resolva o problema. Não há inclusive erro no script da pergunta na parte `end as teste`, porém quando testei no *fiddle* não traz os resultados corretos exatamente por conta do condicional feito dentro de cada `when`, e isso está explicado na resposta

Comment: Se a resposta explica o problema do `when`, traz uma solução funcionando, inclusive com um exemplo no *fiddle*, quem votou negativo poderia ao menos se dar ao trabalho de explicar o voto

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, é uma ótima dica, mas o problema 'as teste' persiste, estou enviando uma issue para o GitHub do phpmyadmin pois aparentemente parece ser um bug do analisador sintático deles, visto que em outros locais a query está correta

Answer (score 1):

Seria assim:

```
SELECT 
c.`nome`, 
c.`cod_municipio`, 
cll.`latitude`, 
cll.`longitude`,
c.`id_estado` as teste
CASE teste
    WHEN 1 THEN 12 
    WHEN 2 THEN 27
    WHEN 3 THEN 13 
    WHEN 4 THEN 16 
    WHEN 5 THEN 29
    WHEN 6 THEN 23
    WHEN 7 THEN 53 
    WHEN 8 THEN 32 
    WHEN 9 THEN 52 
    WHEN 10 THEN 21
    WHEN 11 THEN 31
    WHEN 12 THEN 50 
    WHEN 13 THEN 51
    WHEN 14 THEN 15 
    WHEN 15 THEN 25 
    WHEN 16 THEN 26 
    WHEN 17 THEN 22 
    WHEN 18 THEN 41 
    WHEN 19 THEN 33 
    WHEN 20 THEN 24 
    WHEN 21 THEN 11 
    WHEN 22 THEN 14 
    WHEN 23 THEN 43 
    WHEN 24 THEN 42 
    WHEN 25 THEN 28 
    WHEN 26 THEN 35 
    WHEN 27 THEN 17
END  
FROM `cidade` c
INNER JOIN  cidades_lat_long cll 
ON c.`cod_municipio` = cll.id_geocodee
```

Comment: Por que sua resposta funcionaria com relação aos erros apontados?

Comment: Mutio obrigado pela atenção, mas parece não resolver o problema >Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'CASE teste'

Comment: faltou uma virgula dps de `as teste`, isso segundo w3scools